# 100% height <div> inside a fullpage div (top:0, bottom:0)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Problem is simple.

I want a full height div (#inner) inside another full height div (#outer, but with paddings).

This code is rendered correctly in firefox and IE8 but not in IE7 and IE6.

**Edit:** In the context I use this structure, I forced to set postition:absoulte for #outer.

http://jsfiddle.net/8wVQp/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><body>
<style>
#outer {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 left:0; 
 padding: 50px;
 background-color: #FEE;
 height:auto;
}
#inner {
 height:100%;
 background-color: #FDD;
}
</style>
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: **Edit:** In the context I use this structure, I forced to set postition:absoulte for #outer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug in IE6 & IE7.. you need to set the outer div with fixed height for the inner div to behave properly.

change your CSS to something like this

```
<style>
#outer {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 left:0; 
 padding: 50px;
 background-color: #FEE;
 height:140px; /* notice the height is in pixels not % */
}
#inner {
 height:100%;
 background-color: #FDD;
}
```

things would start to work.. you can use javascript to identify the browser & apply the css accordingly.

Comment: i don't think it's quite what he wants. #outer width is `auto`, therefore can change when you resize browser window.

Comment: I understand that he wants to keep the height as 'auto', the issue here is that the inner div isn't taking up 100% space of the outer div, the reason can be attributed to a bug in IE6 & IE7.. the only way (at least the one I've found to be working fine) is to give the parent div a fixed height...

Answer (score 0):

if the parent is already full height, you should use `height: 100%` and not `position`.

Comment: Parent is <body> and it's not 100% height!

Answer (score 0):

for the #outer don't use `height:auto`. Make it `height:100%`.

Comment: With height:100%, paddins heights are also added to <div>'s height